# Co-worker fired, now I am the only worker left in my department

Tags: colleagues, new-job, learning

To cut a long story short; I started working at a new company where it was me and another coworker doing all the work. He had been at this company for 5 months. He was the one that trained me and now he is gone. The manager is new at the company as well. He does not know much as to what is going on. I am the only person left in this department, completely new at my role. Now, I have been with the company for 2.5 weeks.

Is there any hope? What should I do?

Comment: all the work = our departments work

Comment: coworker was fired

Comment: What is your goal? What is your question?

Comment: `Am I screwed?` - In what way? `Is this a positive for me down the road?` - Down the road? What road? At this company? There's no way for any of us to answer your question. We have no knowledge of the company, their financial position, their market viability, etc., etc. If this situation makes you uncomfortable and unsure of your future prospects at this company or of the company's long term viability then maybe you should look for a position elsewhere.

Comment: Hows the company going? Is it on shaky grounds or is it robust in its business likely to continue? Do they have a track record of this sort of thing?  If someone who had only been there for 5 months was senior enough to train someone I'd be looking at these potential red flags.  You are indeed possibly screwed, yes.

Comment: This is entirely positive for you.  Demand more money.

Answer (score 3):

It's not your problem to solve, it's the companies problem. Do what you can, look for documentation etc,. and don't worry about it until you have to.

Comment: In this situation basically all the problems are not your problem.  The fact that you now know more than anybody else in the company about your department, but are only there for 2.5 weeks, gives you massive amount of opportunities.  **MASSIVE**.  Do your best, don't commit crimes, and you'll most likely do well.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you think You are screwed? 
What type of position/company is it? Do they have a high turnover rate?

If it’s sales it sounds normal, if it’s HR then I’d question it deeper.

All in all I would speak with your direct boss regarding your concerns and try to figure it out that way.